# Fixed Navbar header off top of screen with Cordova on iphone 5 and 6

Tags: ios, cordova, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am developing a Cordova 5.1 app using AngularJS and Angular's Bootstrap implementation.  Everything looks good in Android and even in the iPhone 4 emulator but on the emulators for iphone 5 and 6 my fixed navbar at the top of the screen isn't visible.  I can pull down and it scrolls into place but disappears when I release the pull.  It appears that the viewport is larger than the screen and is thus pushing the navbar up and out of sight.

If I rotate the emulator then everything is visible although it remains in a portrait mode.

Comment: Add some sample code.